# "to a bit of what is all around you". Is it grammatically right?

Tags: prepositions, idioms, lyrics

Song "Martha, my dear" (by Beatles) contains these lines:

> When you find yourself in the thick of it.
>
> Help yourself to a bit of what is all around you.

I don't understand why part `to a bit of what is all around you` is grammatically right.

I suppose that this part should look something like: `Help yourself to take a bit of what is all around you`.

I would like to know what this part exactly means and why it is grammatically right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *to* in this phrase is a preposition. *To help yourself to* something means to serve yourself something. For example: *Help yourself to a piece of pie.* *Help yourself to some ice cream.*

Answer (score 1):

There is not usual word-order here as far as it is poetical text, however, grammatically it looks correct.

> *Help yourself to* + noun-phrase.

Looking from syntactical point of few, here it is a noun phrase (preposition phrase) where *a bit* is instead of the head noun, and the subordinate clause is *what is all around you* (the dependent is complement-type).